# Redirect Google Authentication to Microsoft Authentication to use with SAML

Tags: google-cloud-platform, entra-id, saml, google-cloud-identity

At this point I have an issue where I want to login to Google Identity's assets but using Azure AD as the IdP (Identity Provider).

I already have the whole SAML environment setup with google as the SP and Azure as the IdP. Now, the issue here is when I call an oauth2 login to google I get the google Login page first, and then the Microsoft Login page. Obviously this isn't what we want.

I want to be able to click a link to access google apps, and google itself redirects me to Azure Login page, without ever using Google's login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "when I call an oauth2 login to google I get the google Login page first" you mean that you get the page where you have to enter the username, and after Google sees the user is from a domain that has SAML SSO configured it redirects you to Microsoft, that's expected. Google needs to know which user is being authenticated to know where to redirect you.

If you control the OAuth2 app, you can add the [`login_hint` parameter](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#login-hint) to specify the user, which would let Google redirect it to SAML SSO sooner.